# Do we pay for storage when we stop (suspend) a Kusto & ADX cluster?

Tags: azure-data-explorer

This question is for both -- Kusto as well as ADX cluster. On the azure overview page of a cluster we do see 'Stop' option and it says in the tip 'No compute charges'. So, does it mean we will keep paying for the underlying storage accounts (even if the storage accounts are not in our subscription , these are auto created by Kusto) until the cluster is hard deleted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Storage artifacts that are haven't been hard deleted (according to the effective retention policies set on entities in your cluster, while it wasn't suspended) nor have been purged -  remain in the persistent storage of your cluster, as long as your cluster hasn't been deleted.

Thus, when you suspend your cluster, you still pay for having them stored.

- Note that these artifacts are compressed (and have a smaller size than the original size of your data).
- This is commonly not a major contributor to the cost of your cluster.

No read/write transactions are done against these storage artifacts while your cluster is suspended (so you don't pay for such transactions).